# wordpress: get json - js to php

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress

I have a JSon object in a js page.
I want to receive this data in a php page.

Page: ajax.js:

```
var campi={0: {1: ' ', 2: ' ', 3: ' '}};
campi=JSON.stringify(campi); //thank you @Musa
$.ajax({
    url: example_ajax_obj.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'action': 'example_ajax_request',
        'campi' : campi
    },
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(campi);             
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Page: page.php

```
function example_ajax_request() {
    $campi = $_POST['campi']; 
    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $campi . "' );</script>";
    $json_data = json_decode($campi, true);
    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $json_data . "' );</script>";
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

Consolle shows me:

-Debug Objects:              //due to echo "console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $campi . "' );";

-Debug Objects: Array        //due to echo "console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $json_data . "' );";

{0: {1: ' ', 2: ' ', 3: ' '}}

I can't figure the reason why it doesn't work and I don't know how to debug.
Thank you guys

Comment: Using your web browser's inspection tool, do you see the outgoing network request bring made? Have you imported the jQuery library in your javascript? Any error in the JS console? Change _post_ to _POST_?

Comment: I see the"console.log(campi);" and it's correct.
JS Consolle doesn't show any error.
I changed into 'POST', but nothing changes.

Comment: Do you see the outgoing network request?

Comment: I used 'inspect', 'network' and i see the files 'ajax.js', the 'page.php' is missing. I see the file. Is it what you asking for? Sorry but I'm new to debugging

Answer (score 0):

`campi` is not JSON, you'll have to convert it to JSON before you send it

```
$.ajax({
    url: example_ajax_obj.ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        'action': 'example_ajax_request',
        'campi' : JSON.stringify(campi) //<-- here
    },
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(campi);             
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: I converted using stringify. I see it correctly in the console, but I can't use it in php page.